# sync task for retrofit2.0 showing wrong response for first time

Tags: android, performance

I want to perform sync task ,So I done by following way

```
public boolean checkAuthentication(final long clientId, final String strDeviceCode) {
Webservice webservice = APIUtils.getWebsevice(Webservice.class);
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    final Call<Boolean> res = webservice.isAuthenticate(clientId, strDeviceCode);
                    retrofit2.Response<Boolean> newResponse = res.execute();
                    if (newResponse.code() == 200)
                        isValid = true;
                    else
                        isValid = false;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
        return isValid;
    }
```

And I called this method onClick of button ,by just printing the Toast (for testing purpose)

```
Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, ""+config.checkAuthentication(clientId, strDeviceCode), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But what is happening ,when I click on the button for the first time (for right credentials) it shows false ,and when I click again then it shows true.**I done the same by .enqueue() too**  Why is this happening? And what should I do to get the correct output?

Comment: You cannot use network calls in a synchronous task.

Comment: means? can you please explain?

Comment: In your code the statement `return isValid;` will be called before the statement `isValid = true;`

Comment: yes that is what happening. I don't know how to solve  this issue.Please help

Comment: show a non-canceleable progress dialog before making the server call, then dismiss the progress dialog only after the call is completed. After that you can directly use the variable without making any network calls.

Comment: not happening by this way. Thanks for the help.